# Google maps does not get the user location if the user does not have a recent location

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, location

I have encountered a problem when getting the users current location if the user does not have any recent location the map cannot find the current location but if I allow other apps on location then going back to my application the map can now see the current location.

I tried doing another code for the current location because the one that I am currently using is deprecated, when I run the application it does not get the users current location but if I have a recent location using other application my app can now get the user location, . Here is my code.

```java
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    public static int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;

    private final LatLng MarisolTerminal = new LatLng(15.1519204,120.4476555);
    private final LatLng VillaTerminal = new LatLng(15.1268318,120.5974806);
    private final LatLng CheckpointTerminal = new LatLng(15.169206,120.5872296);

    private Marker markerMarisolTerm;
    private Marker markerVillaTerminal;
    private Marker markerCheckpointTerminal;

    private LocationCallback locationCallback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);



        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        if (mapFragment != null) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        checkLocationPermission();

    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        mMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this,R.raw.custom_map_style)
        );





        // Add some markers to the map, and add a data object to each marker.
        markerMarisolTerm = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(MarisolTerminal)
                .title("Marisol Terminal")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marisol)));
        markerMarisolTerm.setTag(0);

        markerVillaTerminal = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(VillaTerminal)
                .title("Villa Terminal")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.villa)));
        markerVillaTerminal.setTag(0);

        markerCheckpointTerminal = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(CheckpointTerminal)
                .title("Checkpoint Terminal")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.checkpoint)));
        markerCheckpointTerminal.setTag(0);


    }


    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            getUserLocation();


        } else {
            requestForPermission();
        }


    }

    private void getUserLocation() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();

        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                if (location !=null){

                    double lat = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(lat, longitude);


                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("I am here"));
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void requestForPermission(){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE){
            if (grantResults [0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getUserLocation();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Denied" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

getLastLocation only returns a result if the Location subsystem already has data.  It does not start the location subsystem.  It should almost never be used.  Use getCurrentLocation or requestLocationUpdates, both of which will start the location subsystem instead.